# Terminology "upper" Ahlfors regular measure

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, terminology, metric-spaces, fractals

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $m$ be a Borel measure on $(X,d)$.  The measure $m$ is called Ahlors regular if $m(B(x,r))\asymp r^q$ for some $q>0$ and each $x\in X$.  Is there a name for measures satisfying the following relaxation:

There is some strictly monotone continuous increasing function $\omega:[0,\infty]\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ with $\omega(0)=0$ and $\omega(\infty)=\infty$ satisfying:
$$
m(B(x,r)) \leq \omega(r);
$$
what about in the simple case where $\omega(r)=r^q$ for some $q>0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case $\omega(r) = Cr^q$:

- the terminology "upper Ahlfors ($q$-)regular" is certainly in use. See, e.g., https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.04819.pdf .
- the terminology "($q$-)Frostman measure" is also used, referring to [Frostman's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frostman_lemma). See, e.g., [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jazzam/posts/2020-01-14-frostmann/](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ejazzam/posts/2020-01-14-frostmann/) .

In the case of a general $\omega$, I personally do not know of a name. I might call it some kind of "upper mass bound".

Comment: Thanks for the links and terminological tip.  May I ask, is there typical examples of upper Ahlfors regular measures?